# Spring Boot Java Application Memory

Tags: java, memory, limit

I have made an application using spring boot application and tested its memory consumption using visual VM. My applications heap size is increasing constantly while the used heap size is fluctuating. Sharing the stats:
When application started: HeapSize = 700mb and used HeapSpace was 500. When I used the application by hitting 200 rest calls. Stats were HeapSize = 1200mb but this time for usedHeapSpace graph came down and usedHeapSpace was 500.[Screenshot of Visual VM dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/waM4k.png)

Attached is the Screenshot where i stopped the service.

Please can anyone tell me how to control this memory usage as there is no limit for memory size and this will end taking the whole memory of my server as i stopper it to 1800mb

Comment: You need to analyze the heap and find out what's taking up space.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways by which we can tune the usage of JVM memory 
The first and foremost we can use the parameter to control the heap size as

```
java  -Xms512m -Xmx2048m
```

- -Xms  This specifies minimal memory to begin with
- -Xmx Max memory available for our application

For more details follow below Oracle : 
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/web.1111/e13814/jvm_tuning.htm#PERFM150

Comment: I tried -Xmx1024 and its working fine while testing on local system. But we are using Kubernetes to manage docker images and spinnaker for the deployment but its not working on server.